# tsconfig path remapping for JS files

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I had jsconfig before to resolve import paths to do something like `import { api } from '@utils'`, but since introducing TS, I replaced it with tsconfig. 99% of the codebase is still in JS, and in my IDE the imports that use the remapping complain `Module is not installed.`

It seems the imports are only working for TS files.. is this normal or expected? Compile works though, but I don't like the IDE complaining as if I have invalid imports.